Exporting old WhatsApp conversations and dealing with legacy encoded emojis from IOS 4.0
I am trying to export and archive some old WhatsApp conversations from 2012-2013, and visually render them so they appear as if on the phone screen. I found this great piece of software - https://whatsapp-chat-parser.netlify.app/ which allows me to use the exported zip file from a WhatsApp conversation and renders it with pictures reasonably closely to how it appears on my phone.
However I have one problem. Most of these conversations use legacy encoded emojis from IOS 4.0, pre the Unicode 6.0 Standard. They display like this in the exported WhatsApp text file: 
 This is U+E058, which is disappointed face in the legacy standard - but the Unicode disappointed face is U+1F61E. If I create a test WhatsApp conversation put in a disappointed face and export the chat, the basic text file and the software above render the disappointed face correctly () as it uses the most recent Unicode.
My knowledge at this point begins to fail. What I am imagining is some kind of text reader that can display the hex code point, and then I can do some kind of find and replace on U+E058 to make it U+1F61E. Is something like this possible? Or am I barking up the wrong tree on how to approach this problem?
Many thanks for any thoughts on how to proceed.
